Problema al integrar llama 3.1 a mi pagina web con HTML, CSS y JS
El problema es este tengo una página que se especifica por crear artículos de blogs a través de unos prompts que irán al modelo de Llama 3.1, vi una guia para poder integrar el modelo, pero me esta dando error cuando lo ejecuto.
Esta es la guía:
Instalar la biblioteca con: npm install llamaai
Código de prueba
// Importar la biblioteca
import LlamaAI from 'llamaai';

// Inicializar la biblioteca
const apiToken = "Mi-Token";
const llamaAPI = new LlamaAI(apiToken);

// Crear la consulta
const apiConsultaJson = {
   "messages": [
       {"role": "user", "content": "What is the weather like in Boston?"},
   ],
   "functions": [
       {
           "name": "get_current_weather",
           "description": "Get the current weather in a given location",
           "parameters": {
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                   "location": {
                       "type": "string",
                       "description": "The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA",
                   },
                   "days": {
                       "type": "number",
                       "description": "for how many days ahead you wants the forecast",
                   },
                   "unit": {"type": "string", "enum": ["celsius", "fahrenheit"]},
               },
           },
           "required": ["location", "days"],
       }
   ],
   "stream": false,
   "function_call": {"name": "get_current_weather"},
};

// Ejecutar la consulta
llamaAPI.run(apiConsultaJson)
 .then(response => {
    console.log("Bien");
 })
 .catch(error => {
    console.error("Un error ocurrió:", error);
 });

Y este es el error que me da:
node Crear_Articulo.mjs
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
        ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'axios' imported from C:\Users\Bradalis\node_modules\llamaai\index.js
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:910:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1130:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.11.1


Este código que estoy ejecutando, solo es de prueba para ver si funciona, trate de ver si era en el momento de la importación, pero mi archivo termina en .mjs y no creo que sea por eso, aunque también cambie esto: import LlamaAI from 'llamaai'; por esto: const LlamaAI = require("llamaai"); y cambie la extensión a .js, pero aún me sigue dando problemas.

La solución era instalar un paquete que faltaba con el comando: npm install axios y listo, ya se podrá ejecutar.
